# Updating database with file url after successful upload

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried everything within this section and I know it's something noobish that I am forgetting. Whatever I add stops the uploads, but this is currently working to get the image on the server.

```
 protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index) {
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->name = $this->trim_file_name($name, $type, $index);
    $file->size = intval($size);
    $file->type = $type;
    if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
        $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
        $file_path = $this->options['upload_dir'].$file->name;
        $append_file = !$this->options['discard_aborted_uploads'] &&
            is_file($file_path) && $file->size > filesize($file_path);
        clearstatcache();
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
            if ($append_file) {
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );              

            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
            }
        } else {
            // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
            file_put_contents(
                $file_path,
                fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
            );

        }
        $file_size = filesize($file_path);
        if ($file_size === $file->size) {
            if ($this->options['orient_image']) {
                $this->orient_image($file_path);
            }
            $file->url = $this->options['upload_url'].rawurlencode($file->name);
            foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
                if ($this->create_scaled_image($file->name, $options)) {
                    if ($this->options['upload_dir'] !== $options['upload_dir']) {
                        $file->{$version.'_url'} = $options['upload_url']
                            .rawurlencode($file->name);
                    } else {
                        clearstatcache();
                        $file_size = filesize($file_path);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if ($this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
            unlink($file_path);
            $file->error = 'abort';
        }
        $file->size = $file_size;
        $this->set_file_delete_url($file);
    }
    return $file;

}
```

How would I make it so after it uploads it connects to the database and posts the file url to the field I need.

I have been inserting this in the above and it just causes it not to work:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","----","----");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("----", $con);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (postid, post_content)
VALUES ('', 'test_upload_file_name')");

mysql_close($con);

header("Location: http://-----.com/index.php");
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: What does "causes it not to work" mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Your insert as-is into the MYSQL DB won't work. It just inserts the string 'test_upload_file_name' into the database for each file. Perhaps you want to replace it with the value of `$file_path`?

Comment: What I mean by causes it not to work, it stops the image from uploading. Refresh filezilla after testing and nothing is there, take the insert into block out and it uploads the image fine.

Comment: I know I will later need to replace it with $filepath, but I am not sure where to put the code in for it to work, everywhere I try manages to break the upload process.

Comment: Have you checked if `mysql_query()` returns false? Try running a `mysql_error()` after it to see the mysql error. It seems like this should be at the bottom of your script (or you should `die()` after the `header()` so the header gets send and the script stops)

Comment: Nowhere in all of that do I see if you check if the upload actually succeeded. Where do you check `$_FILE['...']['error']`?